# Alert condition question when conditon changes

Tags: alert, pine-script, pine-script-v4

I became member to this site just to ask this question. I would be glad if you could help me solve this issue.
I am not a programmer and have no experience whatsowever. This is part of a pine script for tradingview.

Below is the original script and I want to be able add an alert to it when the condition changes, alert message for both buy and sell.
I was able to write this:

```
alertcondition(Greenbar1 and Greenbar2, title="Buy", message="buy message")
alertcondition(Redbar1 and Redbar2, title="Sell", message="sell message")
```

but want to add something like this too.

`changeCond`

as in

`alertcondition(buySignal, title="SuperTrend Buy", message="SuperTrend Buy!") alertcondition(sellSignal, title="SuperTrend Sell", message="SuperTrend Sell!") changeCond = trend != trend[1] alertcondition(changeCond, title="SuperTrend Direction Change", message="SuperTrend has changed direction!")`

As you can see above, there are three alert signals, one for buy, one for sell, and one for when the direction changes. I want to be able to the same for the script above.
Below is the original code:

---

```
//@version=4
//By Glaz, Modified
//
study("QQE MOD")
RSI_Period = input(6, title='RSI Length')
SF = input(5, title='RSI Smoothing')
QQE = input(3, title='Fast QQE Factor')
ThreshHold = input(3, title="Thresh-hold")
//

src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
//

//
Wilders_Period = RSI_Period * 2 - 1


Rsi = rsi(src, RSI_Period)
RsiMa = ema(Rsi, SF)
AtrRsi = abs(RsiMa[1] - RsiMa)
MaAtrRsi = ema(AtrRsi, Wilders_Period)
dar = ema(MaAtrRsi, Wilders_Period) * QQE

longband = 0.0
shortband = 0.0
trend = 0

DeltaFastAtrRsi = dar
RSIndex = RsiMa
newshortband = RSIndex + DeltaFastAtrRsi
newlongband = RSIndex - DeltaFastAtrRsi
longband := RSIndex[1] > longband[1] and RSIndex > longband[1] ? 
   max(longband[1], newlongband) : newlongband
shortband := RSIndex[1] < shortband[1] and RSIndex < shortband[1] ? 
   min(shortband[1], newshortband) : newshortband
cross_1 = cross(longband[1], RSIndex)
trend := cross(RSIndex, shortband[1]) ? 1 : cross_1 ? -1 : nz(trend[1], 1)
FastAtrRsiTL = trend == 1 ? longband : shortband
////////////////////


length = input(50, minval=1, title="Bollinger Length")
mult = input(0.35, minval=0.001, maxval=5, step=0.1, title="BB Multiplier")
basis = sma(FastAtrRsiTL - 50, length)
dev = mult * stdev(FastAtrRsiTL - 50, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
color_bar = RsiMa - 50 > upper ? #00c3ff : RsiMa - 50 < lower ? #ff0062 : color.gray


//
// Zero cross
QQEzlong = 0
QQEzlong := nz(QQEzlong[1])
QQEzshort = 0
QQEzshort := nz(QQEzshort[1])
QQEzlong := RSIndex >= 50 ? QQEzlong + 1 : 0
QQEzshort := RSIndex < 50 ? QQEzshort + 1 : 0
//  

Zero = hline(0, color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=1)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

RSI_Period2 = input(6, title='RSI Length')
SF2 = input(5, title='RSI Smoothing')
QQE2 = input(1.61, title='Fast QQE2 Factor')
ThreshHold2 = input(3, title="Thresh-hold")

src2 = input(close, title="RSI Source")
//

//
Wilders_Period2 = RSI_Period2 * 2 - 1


Rsi2 = rsi(src2, RSI_Period2)
RsiMa2 = ema(Rsi2, SF2)
AtrRsi2 = abs(RsiMa2[1] - RsiMa2)
MaAtrRsi2 = ema(AtrRsi2, Wilders_Period2)
dar2 = ema(MaAtrRsi2, Wilders_Period2) * QQE2
longband2 = 0.0
shortband2 = 0.0
trend2 = 0

DeltaFastAtrRsi2 = dar2
RSIndex2 = RsiMa2
newshortband2 = RSIndex2 + DeltaFastAtrRsi2
newlongband2 = RSIndex2 - DeltaFastAtrRsi2
longband2 := RSIndex2[1] > longband2[1] and RSIndex2 > longband2[1] ? 
   max(longband2[1], newlongband2) : newlongband2
shortband2 := RSIndex2[1] < shortband2[1] and RSIndex2 < shortband2[1] ? 
   min(shortband2[1], newshortband2) : newshortband2
cross_2 = cross(longband2[1], RSIndex2)
trend2 := cross(RSIndex2, shortband2[1]) ? 1 : cross_2 ? -1 : nz(trend2[1], 1)
FastAtrRsi2TL = trend2 == 1 ? longband2 : shortband2


//
// Zero cross
QQE2zlong = 0
QQE2zlong := nz(QQE2zlong[1])
QQE2zshort = 0
QQE2zshort := nz(QQE2zshort[1])
QQE2zlong := RSIndex2 >= 50 ? QQE2zlong + 1 : 0
QQE2zshort := RSIndex2 < 50 ? QQE2zshort + 1 : 0
//  

hcolor2 = RsiMa2 - 50 > ThreshHold2 ? color.silver :
   RsiMa2 - 50 < 0 - ThreshHold2 ? color.silver : na
plot(FastAtrRsi2TL - 50, title='QQE Line', color=color.white, transp=0, linewidth=2)
plot(RsiMa2 - 50, color=hcolor2, transp=50, title='Histo2', style=plot.style_columns)

Greenbar1 = RsiMa2 - 50 > ThreshHold2
Greenbar2 = RsiMa - 50 > upper

Redbar1 = RsiMa2 - 50 < 0 - ThreshHold2
Redbar2 = RsiMa - 50 < lower
plot(Greenbar1 and Greenbar2 == 1 ? RsiMa2 - 50 : na, title="QQE Up", style=plot.style_columns, color=#00c3ff, transp=0)
plot(Redbar1 and Redbar2 == 1 ? RsiMa2 - 50 : na, title="QQE Down", style=plot.style_columns, color=#ff0062, transp=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way:

```
alertcondition(Greenbar1, title="Greenbar1", message="QQE Up1!") 
alertcondition(Greenbar2, title="Greenbar2", message="QQE Up2!") 
alertcondition(Redbar1, title="RedBar1", message="QQE Up1!")
alertcondition(Redbar2, title="RedBar2", message="QQE Up2!")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you wrote make 4 alert conditions.  alertcondition(Greenbar1 and Greenbar2, title="Buy", message="buy message")
alertcondition(Redbar1 and Redbar2, title="Sell", message="sell message") this makes 2 alert conditions. I want to be able to make one alert condition, meaning to combine these two conditions. This code I wrote already works and sends buy message and sell message but the alert has to set twice.

Comment: What I want is to trigger alert whether it is sell or buy message. Normally, buy message is when Greenbar1 and Greenbar2 to is up and sell message when Redbar1 and Redbar2 is down. They are already combined.